# Change the string of the 'key' in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my array

```
[
  {    
    "id": 2,
    "language": {
      "name": "English",
      "abbreviation": "EN"
  }
]
```

To access `language.name`

```
function get(arrName)
{
    for(var k = 0 ; k< arr.length; k++)
    {
        console.log(arr[k].language.name); //English
    }
}
```

In `arr[k].language.name`, i want to put `'language'` string as dynamic, which i am getting it from the params of the function `arrName`.
So that it should be

```
function get(arrName)
{
    for(var k = 0 ; k< arr.length; k++)
    {
        var dynamicArr = '.'+arrName+'.name';
        console.log(arr[k]+dynamicArr);
    }
}
```

Here it is displaying

```
[object Object].language.name;
```

How to get actual array value?

Comment: Jonathan's answer is what you would like, but to explain your problem, you are attempting to log the value of `arr[k]` plus `dynamicArr` instead of the actual array position.

Comment: Use associative array inside the loop `console.log(arr[k][dynamicArr].name);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to access the object property the same way you would with an array, only using the string as the key. Like so:

```
function get(arrName)
{
    for(var k = 0 ; k< arr.length; k++)
    {
        console.log(arr[k][arrName].name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(arr[k][arrName].name);
```

It should be, if I recall properly.

Feel free to take a look at this [dynamic access to an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549744/dynamic-access-to-an-array-in-javascript) for an extensive, iterating code.

Kudos on what you made so far, though.