# Underscore objects, function to get a specific part of the data?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Working with the data object below, I'm trying to write a function which takes in a name (the name being a label from the data, like in this case "GD"), and value. I want to use the function I have written below in underscore but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to write out this code, as I'm new to JS in general. Any input on how to modify the function `getOption()`?

```
var data = [{},{},
  {
   field:"ran",
   indexable:true,
   label:"R",
   options: [
   {},{},
    {
     category_value:"200",
     label:"GD"
    },{},{}
    ]
  },{}
 ]


function getOption (name, value) {
    return _.findWhere(data.options, {label: name}); //return the category_value of the name, if "GD" is the name, the output of this function should be 200
    }
```

Comment: What if there are multiple labels with same name?

Comment: @SandeepNayak That's something I want to account for with this function and had trouble figuring out. Any input?

Comment: `_.findWhere` would only fetch the first match and not subsequent matches

Comment: Is this problem solved? If not, can you make the question a little bit simple? Maybe Just list the Input with 2-3 items, and the output you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs,

> **_.findWhere**(*list*, *properties*)
>
> Looks through the list and
>   returns the first value that matches all of the key-value pairs listed
>   in properties.
>
> If no match is found, or if list is empty, undefined will be returned.
>
> **_.findWhere**(*publicServicePulitzers*, {**newsroom**: *"The New York Times"*});
>   => {year: 1918, newsroom: "The New York Times",   reason: "For its public service in publishing in full so many official reports,
>   documents and speeches by European statesmen relating to the progress
>   and   conduct of the war."}

Looks like you have to specify the property name, and property value. In this case, "label" and "GD" respectively.

Try this:

```
var data = [{},{},
  {
   field:"ran",
   indexable:true,
   label:"R",
   options: [
   {},{},
    {
     category_value:"200",
     label:"GD"
    },{},{} // why so many initalized empty arrays?
    ]
  },{}
 ]


function getOption (name, value) {
    return _.findWhere(data.options, {label: "GD"}); // returns the whole array
    // try var result = _.findWhere(data.options, {label: "GD"});
    // then return result.category_value;
}
```

Just recommended the following url to somewhat related post. It might be of use for you, and it doesn't use an additional library: [dynamic access to an array in javascript](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27549744/dynamic-access-to-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: The data object will have several labels inside of it, is it possible to re-write the `{label: "GD"}` part of the code with something more dynamic? Since it the function will take in any name, and each name has its own label.

Comment: `function getOption (name, value) {
    return _.findWhere(data.options, {name: value});
}`
I suppose. This should work parallel, with the format getOption("label", "GD"). Test at your own risk (as I am sure there is a syntax issue with this one). And I second the motion for multiple results with a same label and value. There is also a "where" function to return all values.